# MySQL style tabs on Toad for MySQL

Tags: mysql, ide, installation, mysql-workbench, toad

Recently I switched from MySQL Workbench to Toad for MySQL and is beginning to like its powerful features. One thing I do miss is the was MySQL manage connections. Every DB Connection in MySQL workbench is a Tab window and then each editor specific to the connection are sub-tabs within the connection tab. You know what I'm saying if you have used MySQL Workbench.

But on Toad for MySQL, every connection and each editor are tabs on same level. It gets messy when you have a lot of connections open. Is there a way to get the MySQL workbench style layout of connections and editor tabs on Toad? I don't think I'm the first one to feel this way.

Thanks!

Comment: This site is for programming questions. Software configuration is offtopic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe you can, but you can hide document tabs for other connections. That would clean up the view.

Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Interface -> Show document tabs for the current connection only.

From that same location, you can also choose to display the tabs vertically which helps when you have many documents open.